# How to choose custom programs to open specific file types?

Tags: 12.04, default

I installed gpicview (to view pictures, as the name suggests). I want it to be the default image viewer program, but it is not listed in the application list (Right click on an image-> Properties-> Open with...). I also downloaded some programs (not in the repository), and I couldn’t find out how to associate them with a file type.

As I remember it, in some older versions of Ubuntu, there was an option "Browse...", and you could choose the programs you want to use. Is it still possible to do so now?

And I think the "Open with" function looks a bit clumsy, because it lists the same program several times (for some programs installed through Wine). Anyone knows how to fix it?

(I am using Ubuntu 12.04 now)

Edit: pcmanfm works fine in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you click "Show other applications"? That should show all installed apps and you should be able to select gpicview from there.

Comment: There are many programs listed, some repeated (Like Wine Internet Explorer, Wine hh), but not what I want (gpicview). Anyway, why should't we be able to browse for program  like before? Or I have to install some additional software?

Comment: It seems that functionality has been removed from 12.04. I remember what you are talking about, but I haven't had a need to use it, so i never noticed the lack of it. However I also remember that Ubuntu Tweak has an option to set file type management, try giving that a go.

Comment: Thank you for your support, it suggested me to install some additional/alternative software, boywithaxe. I tried pcmanfm and it works great!. How to mark this thread as solved, I can't see the button?

Comment: I'm glad I helped. There should be a gray icon with a tick next to my first answer, clicking that will accept that answer as the solution for your issue.